# Manipulate HTML document loaded into WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have developed my custom solution for this. It happened that the first solution is using [XPath queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355386/using-xpath-and-webbrowser-control-to-select-multiple-nodes) and the second, a conceptually similar to the first one, is using CSS queries processed by [sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com/)

Here is the sample code for the second solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myTest.WinFormsApp
{
    public partial class MainFormForSizzleTesting : Form
    {
        public MainFormForSizzleTesting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
                <html>
                <body>
                <img alt=""0764547763 Product Details"" 
                    src=""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AK1MRIi7L._AA160_.jpg"">
                <hr/>
                <h2>Product Details</h2>
                <ul>
                <li><b>Paperback:</b> 648 pages</li>
                <li class=""test""><b>Publisher:</b> Wiley; Unlimited Edition edition (October 15, 2001)</li>
                <li><b>Language:</b> English</li>
                <li class=""test""><b>ISBN-10:</b> 0764547763</li>
                </html>
            ";
        }

        private void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var processor = new WebBrowserControlCSSQueriesProcessor(webBrowser1);

            // change attributes of the first element of the list
            {
                var li = processor.GetHtmlElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = string.Format("<span style='text-transform: uppercase;font-family:verdana;color:green;'>{0}</span>", li.innerText);
            }

            // change attributes of the <li> elements with class = "test"
            var list = processor.GetHtmlElements("li.test");
            foreach (var li in list)
            {
                li.innerHTML = string.Format("<span style='text-transform: uppercase;font-family:verdana;color:blue;'>{0}</span>", li.innerText);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enables IE WebBrowser control to evaluate CSS queries
        /// by injecting sizzle.js (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/1.9.1/sizzle.min.js)
        /// and to return CSS queries results to the calling C# code as strongly typed
        /// mshtml.IHTMLElement and IEnumerable<mshtml.IHTMLElement>
        /// </summary>
        public class WebBrowserControlCSSQueriesProcessor
        {
            private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser _webBrowser;
            public WebBrowserControlCSSQueriesProcessor(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser)
            {
                _webBrowser = webBrowser;
                injectScripts();
            }

            private void injectScripts()
            {
                // Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998996/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control
                HtmlElement head = _webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                HtmlElement scriptEl = _webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
                mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                element.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/1.9.1/sizzle.min.js";
                head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

                string javaScriptText = @"
                        function GetElementsByCSSQuery (cssQuery) {
                            var items = Sizzle(cssQuery);
                            var elements = new Object();
                            var elementIndex = 1;
                            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                              elements[elementIndex++] = items[i];
                            }
                            elements.length = elementIndex -1;
                            return elements;
                            };
                       ";
                scriptEl = _webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
                element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                element.text = javaScriptText;
                head.AppendChild(scriptEl);            
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets Html element's mshtml.IHTMLElement object instance using CSS query
            /// </summary>
            public mshtml.IHTMLElement GetHtmlElement(string cssQuery)
            {
                string code = string.Format("Sizzle('{0}')[0];", cssQuery);
                return _webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { code }) as mshtml.IHTMLElement;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets Html elements' IEnumerable<mshtml.IHTMLElement> object instance using CSS query
            /// </summary>
            public IEnumerable<mshtml.IHTMLElement> GetHtmlElements(string cssQuery)
            {
                // Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278275/accessing-properties-of-javascript-objects-using-type-dynamic-in-c-sharp-4
                var comObject = _webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { string.Format("GetElementsByCSSQuery('{0}')", cssQuery) });
                Type type = comObject.GetType();
                int length = (int)type.InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);

                for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
                {
                    yield return type.InvokeMember(i.ToString(), BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null) as mshtml.IHTMLElement;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I'm running the above sample code I'm getting the following expected test results:

[image: Test results]

Could you please review the code and post your notes and remarks on what could be improved in it?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This looks like your button is called `cmdTest`, why? [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is generally considered a bad thing and even then, why `cmd` for a button? I think a good name for that button would be `TestButton`.

---

```
WebBrowserControlCSSQueriesProcessor
```

That name is way too long, why not shorten it to something like `WebBrowserCssProcessor`?

---

```
li.innerHTML = string.Format("<span style='text-transform: uppercase;font-family:verdana;color:green;'>{0}</span>", li.innerText);
li.innerHTML = string.Format("<span style='text-transform: uppercase;font-family:verdana;color:blue;'>{0}</span>", li.innerText);
```

These two lines are almost the same, consider extracting them into a method:

```
private static void ChangeStyle(mshtml.IHTMLElement element, string color)
{
    element.innerHTML = string.Format(
        "<span style='text-transform: uppercase;font-family:verdana;color:{1};'>{0}</span>",
        element.innerText, color);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ChangeStyle(li, "green");
ChangeStyle(li, "blue");
```

---

```
/// Enables IE WebBrowser control to evaluate CSS queries
/// by injecting sizzle.js (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/1.9.1/sizzle.min.js)
```

Why link the included version of the file here? If I need to know that, I can look at the source code. I would either give no link here (and assume people can google sizzle.js) or link to [the main page](http://sizzlejs.com/).

---

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
```

No need to spell out the whole namespace every time, when you have `using System.Windows.Forms` at the top of your file.

The same applies to the `mshtml` namespace: you should put that into a `using`.

---

```
HtmlElement scriptEl = _webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/1.9.1/sizzle.min.js";

…

scriptEl = _webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = javaScriptText;
```

I don't have much experience with `WebBrowser` or `mshtml`, but why are you using `mshtml` here in the first place? Why not just use the `HtmlElement` directly:

```
scriptEl.SetAttribute("src", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/1.9.1/sizzle.min.js");

scriptEl.InnerText = javaScriptText;
```

Also, reusing variables (`scriptEl` and `element`) like this is not great. You should use different variables here (e.g. `sizzleScriptElement` and `functionScriptElement`).

---

```
_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { code }) as mshtml.IHTMLElement
_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { string.Format("GetElementsByCSSQuery('{0}')", cssQuery) })
```

Repeated code again, so extract it into a method again:

```
public T Eval<T>(string code)
{
    return (T)_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { code });
}
```

Notice that I used a cast and not `as`. That's because when an error happens, cast gives you immediately a clear `InvalidCastException`, while `as` gives you a confusing `NullReferenceException` later.

---

```
public IEnumerable<mshtml.IHTMLElement> GetHtmlElements(string cssQuery)
{
    // Thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278275/accessing-properties-of-javascript-objects-using-type-dynamic-in-c-sharp-4
    var comObject = _webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { string.Format("GetElementsByCSSQuery('{0}')", cssQuery) });
    Type type = comObject.GetType();
    int length = (int)type.InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);

    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        yield return type.InvokeMember(i.ToString(), BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null) as mshtml.IHTMLElement;
    }
}
```

From the linked question, it seems that accessing `length` using `dynamic` works, if you do it from JS first. I would do that, since it means you avoid writing all that reflection code.

Comment: thank you. You're correct on code refactorings you proposed but my question wasn't about code refactoring but about JavaScript and IE WebBrowser control communication technique used in my sample code. Is it correctly done? May I use it for real life applications? Couldn't it result in some side effects I'm currently missing?

Comment: @ShamilS Well, I don't have any experience with these things, so I can't answer that. But answers on CR can be ["about any or all facets of the code"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so if you don't want that, you probably shouldn't post here.

Comment: As I have already noted all your proposals on code refactorings of my sample code are OK with me but they do not cover "Performance" and  "Correctness in unanticipated cases" maybe also "Security issues" - all that three topics AFAIS are foundation topics of CR together with "Best practices and design patterns".